# Access Modelstate Error - Asp.Net web api identity - Angular 6 - Http Post request

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I am issuing a POST request to register a new user details to ASP.NET Web API Identity - Individual User Authentication Account, and it is working perfectly, but in case the username already exist, it returns an error in ModelState of it's response body as follow. I want to access that error in angular to console.log() it.

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Name a@a.a is already taken.","Email 'a@a.a' is already taken."]}}
```

In Angular app =>

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:57310/api/account/register', {password, confirmPassword, email})
.subscribe(data => {console.log(data);this.router.navigate(['/login'])},
(err:HttpErrorResponse)=>console.log(--?--));
```

What should I use instead of --?--

**Update 1:**

I tried `JSON.stringify(err.error.ModelState)`, but it provides

`{"":["Name a@a.a is already taken.","Email 'a@a.a' is already taken."]}`

but I want only

`"Name a@a.a is already taken.","Email 'a@a.a' is already taken."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `JSON.stringify(err.error.ModelState)` provides `{"":["My Error."]}`,

then `JSON.stringify(err.error.ModelState[""]["0"])` provides `My Error.`

Answer (score 1):

If you're solely interested in getting the details of the error message just use:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
```

To see its properties and values.

Comment: It prints the Message part of the response body, but I want to print the ModelState part

Comment: Infact `JSON.stringify(err.error.ModelState)` provides `{"":["My Error."]}` but I want only `My Error.` portion.